# How to create a menu that moves with keys like Yeoman with node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to create a program that uses the terminal in a similar way that Yeoman, that means that you can select some options by moving with the keys.
[image]

How can I do that with node.js any module recommendation or how to do it without modules?

I found this module called [node-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-menu)
but with this one I cannot move with the cursor like Yeoman.

Comment: Yeoman is open source and here's the source: https://github.com/yeoman/yo Have at it.

Comment: @RandyKamradtSr. I will have a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeoman is using [Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js) to make that menu.